# Is it possible for Kakashi to obtain an Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

He doesn't have siblings, nor he is an Uchiha, so the answer would be simple, but as we've seen, he reached a high level in the usage of the Sharingan. so, based on our knowledge of how the Mangekyou Sharingan works, could the combination of his and Obito's eye result an Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan?

Comment: I don't understand most answers. every answer states that for EMS one needs eyes of brother, yet every answer states **technically he can gain EMS**. can everyone be clear as to what they are trying to tell. @krikara answer seems most plausible right now to me.

Comment: @krikara I really like your answer. Since the bounty expires soon, I don't want to loose it for nothing, so I think I'll give it to you, but to be honest, none of these answers fulfilled the role of a proper one. I still don't know that Kakashi can achieve an EMS or not. I know that there isn't an exact source to prove pro or con, but I'm totally confused...The main idea is: you get the bounty, but I won't accept any answers, and hopefully, there will come more interesting theory's, until we can agree in one of them. You've convinced me with the "must be an Uchiha" argument. Keep going bro'!.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to your question is yes, **Kakashi can obtain Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan**.

But the problem is that his Sharingan consumes a lot of his chakra. At some stages, his overuse of Kamui made him exhausted, too. In this **[source](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kamui)**, it does say that:

> "Repeated use of the technique puts a great deal of strain on the
>   user, causing his left eye to bleed if overused"

As a result, **using Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan could result in a life-threatening situation for him**. And as per the previous answer, you need to transplant a Mangekyou Sharingan, preferably from somebody close, such as a sibling.

Comment: Is it possible for kakashi to take obito's MS and gain EMS ?? Because, we all know that kakashi doesn't have siblings. if someone pops in also, it would be impossible for him/her to have MS :P , because he is not from the mighty uchiha clan (I love this clan).

Comment: Theoritically no since Obito is not his sibling [except the fact that they were disciples of the same teacher i.e. Fourth Hokage].But Kakashi obtained Mangekyou Sharingan after killing Rin[even though they were not related apart from being  disciples of the same teacher i.e. Fourth Hokage ].Therefore from what I can speculate is that there could be a chance of him obtaining EMS with Obito's MS.But still,it's upto the hands of Sir Masashi Kishimoto.

Comment: The Mangekyō Sharingan is awakened through the trauma experienced from the death of a person very close to the Sharingan user. Kakashi liked Rin for sure, there's no doubt in that. EMS can be awakened even by transplanting eye of a non-sibling (Though the success rate is less). But, I don't think Kishi will allow Kakashi to have EMS, because already we have enough people to deal with madara.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention the awakening of MS......although i knew about awakening of MS,i didn't specified it in my answer.....but as far as your question is concerned,there could be a 50-50 chance for Kakashi to obtain EMS....

Answer (score 5):

Technically speaking, Kakashi should be able to obtain the Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan. But the chances of this happening are very slim.

To obtain an Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan, one needs to transplant a Mangekyou Sharingan, preferable from somebody close to them such as a sibling. Just a normal transplant should only restore ones eyes sight with its Visual Prowess.

Yet, Kakashi may also be an exception in this case as he  does not/barely seem to lose any of his eyesight when he is using his Sharingan. This might also be due to the lack of use, and the lack of powerful eye powers besides his Kamui.

> Over time, use of the Mangekyō Sharingan's techniques deteriorates the user's eyesight to the point of blindness, a harsh fate for those that have grown accustomed to the power and visual acuity it affords. Only by transplanting the eyes of another Uchiha can they hope to regain their sight and ocular powers. If the transplanted eyes happen to be the Mangekyō Sharingan of an Uchiha with strong blood ties with the recipient — ideally a sibling — the likelihood of compatibility is increased, resulting in the creation of an Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan  [source](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan)

Answer (score 5):

Realistically speaking, **Kakashi cannot gain the Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan (EMS)**.

Reread this section from Chapter 386

[image]

There are multiple reasons why Kakashi cannot gain EMS. First, the exchange must be done between clansmen. Kakashi doesn't fit in this category. Further more, the manga states "simply gaining another's eyes didn't equate to gaining this power". This is implying that you need to gain your brother's eyes as well as a new set of eyes.

One can argue that Kakashi and Obito are like brothers, however Kakashi isn't gaining a new eye if he swaps with Obito.

In the end, it is impossible for Kakashi to achieve EMS.

Comment: well, I'm glad that I've putted a bounty on this, since more and more interesting theorys/opinions are coming(for and against)....but my question is, isn't clansmen referring to the fact,that they are in "relationship" BY Sharingan? It is necessary to be an Uchiha?

Comment: Yup, it is necessary to be an Uchiha. That's why Kakashi doesn't fit in this category :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Kakashi can obtain **Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan**. I would have to disagree with [kakashi's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6730/is-it-possible-for-kakashi-to-obtain-an-eternal-mangekyo-sharingan/6760#6760) though. **EMS** consumes ***lesser chakra*** and puts ***lesser stress*** on the user casting it. Kakashi has to possess a Mangekyou Sharingan eye, assuming it's compatible to him, since it's not possible to obtain EMS just by implanting another set of MS.

So **using EMS would be less life threatening** to him than using MS, since, there is no risk of blindness after obtaining EMS.

Comment: i do have a question..... even if ur statement is correct,you cannot ignore the fact that he is a non uchiha....... keeping that in mind,I came up with my answer

Comment: You mention that Kakashi would need a "pair of Mangekyou Sharingan" before being able to obtain EMS. I was also wondering this, but do you have any evidence to cite for this?

Comment: @Kakashi  Okay, If being an Non-Uchiha hinders him to upgrade to EMS , so, according to that logic, he shouldn't have got the MS in the first place. But, he did got the MS in the normal way being a non uchiha(I mean the way uchiha's get their MS ),Hence, i think upgrading to EMS won't defy this logic and should be same for both Uchiha and non-Uchiha's alike.

Comment: @SamuelSlade My bad, i mean EMS only in his left eye.

Comment: @BoyLittUp just like how Samuel said,I have one more question to raise:-Kakashi's MSis obvious thing so no-doubt about that, but thing which hits on my head constantly is that Kakashi doesn't have Uchiha blood.Since he doesn't have that,we cannot speculate on any conclusion here since his case is an exceptional one.But based on facts obtained in manga and anime,I have to say that Uchiha blood can use sharingan to its fullest.So indirectly it implies that kakashi can't use EMS to the fullest or he would go through eye strain..tat answer is still in oblivious state.. we have to wait for that

Comment: @Kakashi agreed there. Kakashi cannot use the EMS to its fullest abilities. However, this doesn't eliminate the possibility of gaining EMS. Since EMS uses less chakra, he may be able to maintain his EMS longer than his present MS. But , yes he cannot use it to his fullest potential. We could take a hint from nagato too, since he was an uzumaki and could use Rinnegan, though not to his fullest extent. Same with kakashi.

Comment: Should that be "less chakra" and "less stress" instead of "lesser"? Doesn't "lesser" imply that the chakra and stress are of an inferior nature rather than that less is being consumed?

Answer (score 0):

Since we're stuck, let's sum up what we know:

1. YES - but: his Sharingan uses too much chakra, therefore he would be fully exhausted/maybe dead using the EMS, or he wouldn't be able to use it at its full power.
2. NO - because: Kakashi doesn't belong to the Uchiha clan, plus he doesn't have brothers or close ones to him with the same ability; even if he had someone, that someone must possess an MS, but we don't know about other people, except Sasuke.

So we could say that the odds are even, but it just hit me... Do we realize that we are talking about the same eyes??? As much as I would like to see him equipped with an EMS, if he could gain this eye by simply fusing his one with Obito's one, it would be the same as Madara would've fused his own eyes into one (we can argue that he would lose one eye, but the other would be an EMS), so practically every Uchiha member could've possessed an EMS just by fusing their own eyes.

So if we must make a conclusion, even if he isn't an Uchiha, nor he has siblings, therefore he doesn't got a chance to obtain a new set of eyes, I think the best answer and reason why Kakashi CAN'T obtain an Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan (but I'm eagerly waiting for "can answers") is because fusing your own eyes wouldn't result in EMS.

Answer (score -1):

I think Kakashi's sharingan is already a mangekyou sharingan since mangekyou sharingan users lose their sight for overusing their mangekyou sharingan but kakashi has been using it for a while. However, he has chakra problems given that he is not from the Uchiha clan.

Answer (score -2):

Kakashi is able to obtain EMS from another MS if obtained. He can't transplant Obitos MS that's stupid each MS eye left, right have there own powers, besides this they are the same exact MS so there won't be any difference.
When someone has MS and wants a EMS needs another MS from another person (Clanmate) to obtain EMS by combining those 2 MS they both combine their forms to make a mix like form for the new EMS.

One thing I'm curious we saw Madara with his brother when he got his eyes they mixed and became a new form,same thing with Sasuke with Itachi eyes.
But I can't understand when Sasuke fought with Itachi, Itachi wanted Sasuke's eyes even though they weren't MS. I thought to obtain EMS you need both users' eyes to be MS with different form to make a new form which would be the EMS, but the way Itachi was going its like transplanting normal Sharingan with a MS to make an EMS if that was so and would work what would the new EMS form would look like?

Comment: I'm quite sure, he didn't want to take Sasuke's sharingans...you're misoriented...